# Rotate polygons without cutting edges

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection, data-augmentation

I am writing an augmentation code to rotate annotated polygons inside images. I wrote a code but it's not working right. Just Copy paste the code and you can get the results. Thank you for helping me out.

**Image:**

[image]

Need to rotate the image as well as a polygon for respective angle. Currently, I am not able to rotate the polygon

[image]

The image is rotated but the polygon is still in its place.

I tried This code. It rotates the polygon but not at the right position

```
import math
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from PIL import ImagePath 
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sin, cos, radians
import requests
from io import BytesIO

def rotatePolygon(polygon, degrees, height, width):
    """ 
    Description:
    
        Rotate polygon the given angle about its center. 
        
    Input:
        polygon (list of tuples)  : list of tuples with (x,y) cordinates 
                                    e.g [(1,2), (2,3), (4,5)]
        
        degrees int               : Rotation Degrees
    
    Output:
    
        polygon (list of tuples)  : Polygon rotated on angle(degrees)
                                e.g [(1,2), (2,3), (4,5)]
    
    """
    # Convert angle to radians
    theta = radians(degrees)  
    
    # Getting sin and cos with respect to theta
    cosang, sinang = cos(theta), sin(theta) 

    # find center point of Polygon to use as pivot
    y, x = [i for i in zip(*polygon)]
    
    # find center point of Polygon to use as pivot
    
    cx = width / 2
    cy = height / 2
    
    # Rotating every point
    new_points = []
    for x, y in zip(x, y):
        tx, ty = x-cx, y-cy
        new_x = (tx*cosang + ty*sinang) + cx
        new_y = (-tx*sinang + ty*cosang) + cy
        new_points.append((new_y, new_x))
    return new_points



# Polygon
xy = [(85, 384), (943, 374), (969, 474), (967, 527), (12, 540), (7, 490)]
degrees = 270


# Getting Image from URL
try:
    img = Image.open("polygon_image.png")
except:
    url = "https://github.com/SohaibAnwaar/Mask---RCNN-Polygons-/blob/main/2_image_augmentation/extras/problamatic_image.jpg?raw=true"
    response = requests.get(url)
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    img.save("polygon_image.png")



# Rotating Image
rotated_image = img.rotate(degrees,expand = True)
h, w = img.size

print("NotRotated", xy)
rotated_xy = rotatePolygon(xy, 360 - (degrees), h, w)



# Ploting Rotated Image
img1 = ImageDraw.Draw(rotated_image)  
img1.polygon(rotated_xy, fill ="#FFF000", outline ="blue") 


# Ploting Straight Image
img1 = ImageDraw.Draw(img)  
img1.polygon(xy, fill ="#FFF000", outline ="blue") 

plt.imshow(rotated_image)
plt.show()


plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I tried your answer but not helping me out. Still edges are cutting while rotated polygons

Comment: Its working with rotated_image = img.rotate(degrees,expand = False) but I need to get it done with rotated_image = img.rotate(degrees,expand = True)

Comment: This is not your answer, but; Couldn't you draw a polygon inside the original image before displaying it, and then just rotate that image? In this case, the polygon would rotate in its original position. Do you need polygonal coordinates after rotation? If not this is not a difficult solution.

Comment: Yaa, I need polygon coordinates. It's easy to draw a polygon on an image and get the rotated polygon mask. But I need to rotate all polygon with mathematical equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotation equations are:

```
xnew = x * cos(theta) - y * sin(theta)
ynew = x * sin(theta) + y * cos(theta)
```

only mistake you are doing is this:

```
new_x = (tx*cosang - ty*sinang) + cy
new_y = (tx*sinang + ty*cosang) + cx
```

After rotating image, cx and cy should be changed

Your complete code is as below:

```
import math
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from PIL import ImagePath 
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sin, cos, radians
import requests
from io import BytesIO

def rotatePolygon(polygon, degrees, height, width):
    """ 
    Description:
    
        Rotate polygon the given angle about its center. 
        
    Input:
        polygon (list of tuples)  : list of tuples with (x,y) cordinates 
                                    e.g [(1,2), (2,3), (4,5)]
        
        degrees int               : Rotation Degrees
    
    Output:
    
        polygon (list of tuples)  : Polygon rotated on angle(degrees)
                                e.g [(1,2), (2,3), (4,5)]
    
    """
    # Convert angle to radians
    theta = radians(degrees)
    
    # Getting sin and cos with respect to theta
    cosang, sinang = cos(theta), sin(theta) 

    # find center point of Polygon to use as pivot
    y, x = [i for i in zip(*polygon)]
    
    # find center point of Polygon to use as pivot
    
    cx1 = width[0] / 2
    cy1 = height[0] / 2
    cx2 = width[1] / 2
    cy2 = height[1] / 2
    
    # Rotating every point
    new_points = []
    for x, y in zip(x, y):
        tx, ty = x-cx1, y-cy1
        new_x = (tx*cosang - ty*sinang) + cx2
        new_y = (tx*sinang + ty*cosang) + cy2
        new_points.append((new_y, new_x))
    return new_points



# Polygon
xy = [(85, 384), (943, 374), (969, 474), (967, 527), (12, 540), (7, 490)]
degrees = 270


# Getting Image from URL
try:
    img = Image.open("polygon_image.png")
except:
    url = "https://github.com/SohaibAnwaar/Mask---RCNN-Polygons-/blob/main/2_image_augmentation/extras/problamatic_image.jpg?raw=true"
    response = requests.get(url)
    img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    img.save("polygon_image.png")



# Rotating Image
rotated_image = img.rotate(degrees,expand = True)
h1, w1 = img.size
h2, w2 = rotated_image.size

print("NotRotated", xy)
rotated_xy = rotatePolygon(xy, degrees, [h1,h2], [w1,w2])



# Ploting Rotated Image
img1 = ImageDraw.Draw(rotated_image)  
img1.polygon(rotated_xy, fill ="#FFF000", outline ="blue") 


# Ploting Straight Image
img1 = ImageDraw.Draw(img)  
img1.polygon(xy, fill ="#FFF000", outline ="blue") 

plt.imshow(rotated_image)
plt.show()


plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: did you tried the thing ? because its not helping me out.

Comment: yes, its working fine for me. I can upload the whole code also.

Comment: yaa please, upload it I will be really thankful to you

Comment: tried but Still working, Try it on 180 ,45, 90, 270,

Comment: you have to change cx cy according to the rotated image. In general, it will be `cx = width(rotated_image)/2` and `cy = height(rotated_image)/2`

Comment: doing the same. In code first rotate the image get its height, width and then pass it to function for polygon rotation with rotated image h, w. I tried your code on 180 but its failing

Comment: Let me check again. I haven't tried it with 180.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236572/discussion-between-sohaib-anwaar-and-user8190410).

Answer (score 0):

For a rotation to the right by a right angle, use the following equations (assuming `X`/`U` left-to-right and `Y`/`V` top-down):

```
U = H - Y
V = X
```

where the image size is `W x H`.

Comment: But Where do I have to put this equation?

Comment: @SohaibAnwaar: these are the rotation equations, of course !?

Comment: Sorry! But I am not able to understand. Will you please be a little more precise thank you. Need to solve this problem.

Comment: @SohaibAnwaar: well, where are your rotation equations, currently ?